# Which listview event can be used after a ListViewItem.Add?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, controls

how can autoscroll the listview, if add an listviewitem to listview. That can i do, with this:

```
this.listView1.EnsureVisible(this.listView1.Items.Count - 1);
```

But i dont want to add this line after all Item.Add() function. I want do this with an listview event, which i should use?

Is there an event like listView1_ItemAdded()! What could i use?

Bevor i thanks all answers.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what it is you want to do. Here's the full list of Events for your listview.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_events.aspx

Comment: There's some measure of sanity in the native Windows controls, they only generate events for things that happen beyond your control.  There is no way that the user can add an item to a ListView, only you can do it with your own code.  So it doesn't make much sense to have an event to tell you about something you already know about.  Just fire your own event in the code that adds an item.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english syntax, but i have the solution in the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any event to notify that the item has been added. My suggestion is adding the ListViewItem you need to focus with `Selected` property to `true`, so you mark the item as selected **before** you add it to the ListView

```
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("example");
        item.Selected = true;

        listView.Items.Add(item);
```

As an alternative, you can implement a collection with events, and register the ListViewItems with, here is a short article on extending ListView that covers the subject quite nicely:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4406/An-Observer-Pattern-and-an-Extended-ListView-Event

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh thx, that is it! I will use it with the property ListViewItem.Selected !